# How to setup Thunderbird to sign outgoing email messages with my GPG key?

Tags: thunderbird, gnupg

Signing all outgoing email messages sounds like a good idea and I'm curious to know easy it is to get this set up with Thunderbird.

What steps do I have to take and what settings do I have to change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the `enigmail` package.  This will add the OpenPGP menu to thunderbird and allow you to use gpg to encrypt, sign, and verify email.